# Are there any physical realizations of a rebit (a qubit with real coefficients for probability amplitudes of a two-state system)?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, quantum-computer

While being introduced to the world of quantum computation and qubits, I’ve come across the term ***rebit***, which I understand to mean a two-state quantum system that may be expressed as a real linear combination of $|0\rangle$ and $|1\rangle$ (which can also be considered as restricted states that are known to lie on a longitudinal great circle of the Bloch sphere corresponding to only real state vectors). Much of the work on using rebits seems too abstract for me (see for example https://journals.aps.org/prx/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevX.5.021003) - hence my question is: are there any physical realizations of a rebit, and do they have a place in the toolkit for future quantum computers?

Comment: Rebits certainly lie on a great circle of the Bloch sphere, but I'm not sure that it's typically presented as the equator; in most texts I've seen, $|0\rangle$ and $|1\rangle$ are the north and south poles of the Bloch sphere, which are not on the equator.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out to me - I see what you mean and I'll update my question. Still, I'm struggling intuitively with the concept though - can you think of any system which would constitute a rebit?

Comment: Sorry, I have to say this, since I've just learnt the word rebit: they also come in great numbers from ponds, especially as its spring here and the frogs are laying their eggs with great gusto.